# Auto-delete folders in a directory delete the wrong folders

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a small bash script which will be called monthly by a cronjob.

Given a folder structure like `pingLog -> 2020 -> Jan -> 04` every first of the month it must automatically delete the two months old folder:

```
if [ -d ".../pingLog/$( date +'%Y/%b' -d '2 month ago' )/" ];
then
    sudo rm -r ".../pingLog/$( date +'%Y/%b' -d '2 month ago' )/"        
fi
```

then it must delete the "Year" folder if it is empty:

```
if [ $( "find .../pingLog/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty"; ) ];
then
    sudo rm -r $( "find .../pingLog/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty"; )
fi
```

Something is not working in the scripts (probably the condition of the 2nd if) as folders which are not supposed to verify the if condition are being deleted, but I can't find the error.

## Edit

@dash-o there are 2 problem with your solution. For testing purpose I created a `2019` folder that contain `Nov` (2 months ago).

If I try to manually launch the script after the 2nd time here's the output:

```
Folders: .../pingLog/2019/Nov have been deleted.
Folders: .../pingLog/2019 have been deleted.
find: ‘.../pingLog/2019’: No such file or directory
rmdir: missing operand
Try 'rmdir --help' for more information.
```

Here's my 2 problem:

- echo without if condition print even if `find` fail
- I can't print the `find` and `rmdir` output on the file when they fail

Comment: remove the double-quotes from the `command substitution`:`$()`, should be like: `$(find .../pingLog/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty)`

Comment: `...` (3 dots) is probably incorrect syntax.

Comment: I recommend checking in advance that the output of `date +'%Y/%b' -d '2 month ago'` is not empty. Otherwise there could be a surprise.

Comment: 1) Removing the quotes did not solve the problem, take out ```find``` from the quote does.
2) The 3 dots are not a syntax error, it was a way to shorten the folder address.
3) How can I check that the ```date``` output is not empty if not with the if condition I wrote above?

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions to simplify the script, and address the problems.

1. For the removal, no need to test if directory exists. Simply use 'rm -rf' to remove folders associated with the 2 month old folder.
2. For the year removal, you want to modify limit the scope of removal to the previous year log file, AND to use rmdir instead of 'rm -r'. It will reduce the risk of removing other directories, which may contain data.

```
T=.../pingLog
sudo rm -rf "$T/$(date +'%Y/%b' -d '2 month ago')"
find "$T/$(date '+%Y' -d '2 month ago')" -maxdepth 0 -type d -empty | xargs sudo rmdir
```